# How to hide empty columns in HTML Table

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, datatable

So i've got the table below, i want columns to be automatically removed upon the page loading, i should say i am rendering it as PDF. How would i remove the columns that have no data including the header.

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="6" width="100%" class = "table1">
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th title="Field #1">test 1</th>
                        <th title="Field #2">test 2</th>
                        <th title="Field #3">test 3</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                <apex:repeat value="{!qli}" var="opp">
                    <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!opp.test1}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!opp.test2}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!opp.test3}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </apex:repeat> 
            </table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rendered` attribute.

Your code will be

```
              <table border="1" cellpadding="6" width="100%" class = "table1">
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th title="Field #1">test 1</th>
                        <th title="Field #2">test 2</th>
                        <th title="Field #3">test 3</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!qli}" var="opp">    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(opp.test1﻿﻿) , false , true)}" value="{!opp.test1}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(opp.test2﻿﻿) , false , true)}" value="{!opp.test2}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(opp.test3﻿﻿) , false , true)}" value="{!opp.test3}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </apex:repeat> 
            </table>
```

Comment: Would that not just hide the columns rather than the headers? Is there a way to include the headers in that case too.